# Access Form Error: Missing Operator

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax-error

I have a large form with multiple functions, one of the functions is to edit a subform that houses a list of codes and other various pieces of data. When I click the edit button it auto fills the boxes with the selected data, but when I make the edits and try and save it i get the error message: `RUN TIME ERROR 3075 SYNTAX ERROR (MISSING OPERATOR) IN QUERY EXPRESSION`

The whole code is

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    'when we click on button Add there are two options
    '1. For insert
    '2. For Update
    If Me.txt_code.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'this is for insert new
        'add data to table
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO KWTable(KW, Source, Code) " & _
            " VALUES('" & Me.text_key & "','" & Me.combo_source & "','" & _
            Me.txt_code & "')"
    Else
        'otherwise (Tag of txtID store the id of student to be modified)
        CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KWTable " & _
            " SET KW='" & Me.text_key & _
            ", Code='" & Me.txt_code & "'" & _
            ", Source='" & Me.combo_source & "'" & _
            " WHERE KW='" & Me.text_key
    End If

    'clear form
    cmdClear_Click

    'refresh data in list on form
    TableSub.Form.Requery    

End Sub
```

And the portion that is highlighted when I try and debug the issue is.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KWTable " & _
    " SET KW='" & Me.text_key & _
    ", Code='" & Me.txt_code & "'" & _
    ", Source='" & Me.combo_source & "'" & _
    " WHERE KW='" & Me.text_key
```

Comment: Try storing the update statement in a variable before trying to execute the statement. Then open the immediate window and print the variable contents. Then try running THAT in access to see what the real problem is. I think you are missing at least one single quote tho (right before teh comm that comes before Code).

Comment: and you are missing a quote at the end after & Me.text_key.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KWTable " & _
" SET KW='" & Me.text_key & _
"', Code='" & Me.txt_code & "'" & _
", Source='" & Me.combo_source & "'" & _
" WHERE KW='" & Me.text_key + "'"
```

Comment: whats the error? the problem is single quotes and such from what I can see.

Comment: It has the Very beginning Private Sub CmdADD_Click() highlighted now when the syntax error pops up

Comment: Is there an error? It isn't a breakpoint is it (sorry I don't know your level of understanding with this)?

Comment: WHat do you mean exactly. It has the part mentioned highlighted in yellow and then the same code is written in red

Comment: It sounds like you hit a breakpoint. What happens when you hit F10 (or F11)? Does it move to the next statement? From the Debug menu select 'Clear all breakpoints'.

Comment: I did that and it did not change anything

Comment: It just says Compile Error: Syntax Error. when I try and click on the button to run the macro.

Comment: If those are text boxes you will need to include .Text at the end, for instance change 'Me.text_key' to 'Me.text_key.Text'.

Comment: So this is what it looks like:                      CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KWTable " & _
    " SET KW='" & Me.text_key.Text & _
    "', Code='" & Me.txt_code.Text & "'" & _
    ", Source='" & Me.combo_source.memo & "'" &
    " WHERE KW='" & Me.text_key.Text + "'"

Comment: What happens after that? Same error message? What happens when you hard code the UPDATE statement?